# Possibility of validation of transaction TX id

Tags: transactions, transaction-id

I've readed numbers of thread here but non answer to my question. What I want to know if there is a way somehow to validate transactionID ( txID ).

I have a site which accepts bitcoins. In order to validate payments I ask customer to submit txID which I use to look up the transaction. The problem is that customers sometime submit wrong txID, not full txID .. etc.

Is there a way to validate transaction ID **WHEN USER SUBMIT IT TO THE FORM** and if is correct then save it and check it?

Answer (score 1):

A `txid` is little-endian representation of the double `sha256` of the serialized tx. Hence, if they send you a wrong or incomplete `txid` there is no way of validating it without the serialized tx.

Moreover, you should be careful when identifying txs just by its `txid`, if not careful enough (you accept 0-confirmation txs, or txs that has not gone deep enough in the blockchain), they could double spend the same utxo thas has been used to pay you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm asking for somehow validate just user input on frontend. Something like `if($txid_length < 50) elseif ($tx .... )...` for my validation of the payment I have check the blockchain.

Comment: You can check that the ´txid´ length is 64 characters long, since sha256 output is always 256-bit long (32 bytes, 64 hex characters).

However, this will not ensure that the id is correct.